# Calculating difference in years for the whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe with two dates and I want to add a new column that is the difference between the two in years.

```
birthDate  |  created_at                         |  diff_in_years
2000-10    |  2019-06-17 13:15:04.598799+00:00   |
```

I have written the following code to compute the difference. Since I do not know the exact day from `birthDate`, I manually set it to 1 for both. It works great for one row.

```
def convert_to_datetime(str):
    x = int(str[0:4])
    y = int(str[5:7])
    z = 1
    return datetime.datetime(x,y,z)


start_date = "2000-10"
start_date = convert_to_datetime(start_date)
end_date = "2019-06-17 13:15:04.598799+00:00"
end_date = convert_to_datetime(end_date)
diff = relativedelta(end_date,start_date)
```

But the problem is how can I run this computation for the whole dataframe? I've tried the `apply` function but doesn't work. I'm not using it properly.

```
 data.apply(relativedelta(convert_to_datetime(data["created_at"]),convert_to_datetime(data["birthDate"]), axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, try to use the pandas built in function for the datetime conversion :

```py
df['birthDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthDate'])
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
#from here you can just simply substract

df['difference'] = df['created_at'] - df['birthDate'] 
#note that this will give you the difference in days, try to divide by 365 or something like that
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I ran into some timezone and other inconsistency issues, but works now.